# How to stop automatically reading an audio file?

Tags: android, media-player

I've already searched from answers to my question but I didn't found the good one, so there is my problem :

today I'm recording audio files from the MIC device. I record them in the 3gp format.
To record them, I use the code from : http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/audio-capture.html

So I have two buttons, one to **record** and one to **read**. And I want to make change the status from the Read button when the audio file is finished (currently I have to stop manually the MediaPlayer by pressing the button).
I have tried to solve this by using handler, or seekTo(myMediaPlayerName.getDuration()) and it does not worked for me. 
Someone have an idea how to do this?
Thanks, and sorry for my bad english.

Comment: I can show pieces of code if you want, or share screens. Just ask me :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [CountDownTimer](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/CountDownTimer.html) for not stopping manually the MediaPlayer.

```
// Example for 30 seconds
 new CountDownTimer(30000, 1000) {

 public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
    // Do nothing, wait
 }

 public void onFinish() {
   stopMediaPlayer();
 }
}.start();
```